# printing an argument from another class which inherited from different class

Tags: python, super

Apparently, I have 3 different classes; a , b and c.

class a: contain the self.king which was inherited from class b(entered by user)

class b: prompt user to enter the king value and this will be pass to class a

class c: inherit from class a that have the entered king values from class b and which was then pass to class a.

Example of codes:

```
class a(object):
    def __init__(self, king):
        self.king = king

class b(a):
    def __init__(self, king):
        super(b,self).__init__(king=king)

class c(a):
    def __init__(self):
        super(c,self).__init__()
        print(self.king)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bb = b(king="madsfjsfdsdfn")
    cc = c()
    cc
```

Did I do anything wrong here? I get an error such as :

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'king'
```

I thought the value entered in class b has been passed to class a. Since it has been passed to class a, then class c by using super.**init**() will inherits its values and print it accordingly. Did I do it wrongly and understand super() function wrongly?

When user pass value and only 2 class are present:

```
class a(object):
    def __init__(self, king):
        self.king = king

class b(a):
    def __init__(self, king):
        super(b,self).__init__(king=king)
        print(self.king)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bb = b(king="madsfjsfdsdfn")
    bb
```

Then my output is correct:

```
madsfjsfdsdfn
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at it backwards. When you define `class b(a):` it means that `b` inherits from `a` and not the other way around, so when you call `super` on `c`'s `__init__` you're calling `a`.

Basically what happens when you do `c()` (the same as `c.__init__()`), the first line of `c`'s `__init__` function becomes `a.__init__()` (the same as `a()`), and as the error says `a`'s `__init__` function takes the `king` argument and can't be called without such argument.

Besides there's a conceptual misunderstanding between **Classes** and **Objects**, for instance in your code `a`, `b` and `c` are classes (not to mention classes should always start with a capital letter) while `bb` and `cc` are objects. Once you define a class you **won't** be able to inherit attributes modified outside the class definition.

**EDIT**:

After reading several comments I think that what you want is a **static attribute** king, it's important to know that `self` keyword only exists within objects, so by doing `self.king = king` you're saying only `a`'s objects will have a `king` attribute, and not `a` class itself.

Say we have a class `A`:

```
class A(object): 
     p1 = 'static'
     def __init__(self): 
         self.p2 = 'object'
```

I can access `A.p1` or `A().p1` and get `'static'`, `A().p2` will give me `'object'` and `A.p2` will give me an error because `A` it's not an object. If a class inherits from `A` **it will only inherit `p1`**, as `p2` is not static.

I understand that what you want to do is to change this `p1` from instanciating a class that inherits from `A`, say `B`:

```
class B(A): 
     def __init__(self, param): 
         super(B, self).__init__() 
         super.p1 = param
```

the thing is `super` is not actually the parent class, but a built in function that returns an object, so doing this yields:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-ca4dc9978d74> in <module>
----> 1 B(2)

<ipython-input-10-af935ee24ae2> in __init__(self, param)
      2     def __init__(self, param):
      3         super(B, self).__init__()
----> 4         super.p1 = param
      5 
      6 

TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'super'
```

you'd have to do

```
class B(A): 
     def __init__(self, param): 
         super(B, self).__init__() 
         A.p1 = param
```

explicitly modifying the `A` class so that from there, objects which class inherit from `A` would have the new parameter, lets say:

```
class C(A): 
     def __init__(self): 
         super(C, self).__init__() 
         print(self.p1)
```

you can do:

```
print(A().p1)
B('modified')
C()
```

and see that even when the first line will print `'static'`, the last one will print `'modified'`.

Comment: I understand that class should be in capital form but this is just for the sake of brief explanation and a dummy codes so I didnt really check on the codestyle within it. I also understand that class b(a) will inherits from a and also when I call super on c it will call a since it inherits from a. What I wanted to understand is that when I have to prompt user to input new value for "king", I can use super() within class b to change the value in class a. however, after changed it how can class c get the changed values too? I thought since I have executed the class b code first then only call c?

Comment: I put another example. Please kindly check and comment thank you sooooo much

Comment: Edited my answer with an explanation.

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand your example but I wish to have some examples which include multiple classes and that is why I posted this question, if it were to use two classes, I understand that it can be changed in such a way as you stated but what I wish to play around with the code so that I can get more ideas and understanding about the usage of super() is to test it in multiple classes while passing around the constructor values such as self.king in my example for class a to other classes such as class C, D and so on which changed in the class b.

Comment: Most of the examples show two classes and many questions posted also two classes, that is why I posted this time with 3 classes to see whether is it possible to do it.

Comment: Added new class

Answer (score 0):

This example I think meets your specification. The only class that needs a constructor (**init**) is the one where you are storing a value in an instance of the class (creating an object to store a king value).

```
        #Child classes inherit from parent classes 
        class b():
            def prompt_for_king():
                return input("Enter king value!\n")

        class a(b):
            def __init__(self):
                self.king = b.prompt_for_king()

        class c(a):
            pass

        if __name__ == "__main__":
            #instantiate class
            object_c=c()
            print (object_c.king)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is one method to understand basic super() usage but what about when I wanted to prompt user to enter a "king" value and then this entered value will change the self.king within the __init__? I dont want to just print it.

Comment: Yes, as per your specification: class b prompts for the input but the value of king is actually stored within an instance of class a. The print is irrelevant. You can use the stored value of king using object_c.king how you like. As prompt_for_king is only used in the constructor (__init__) you can change the stored value. Try this line at the end of the example above: object_c.king="Arthur" and print object_c.king again. First run  enter a different name, e.g. "William". If you want something else please expand you description of what behaviour you are trying implement.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply and I fully understand what you meant, however, is there a way to pass this stored value which was called in class b(from my example) and passed as instance of class a and then inherit it to class c? I would like to learn this problem since I understand that using super() I could inherit instances from its parents but I get confused when I try this case problem.

Comment: class a(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.yes = "man"

        
    
class c(a):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print(self.yes)

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    cc = c()

Answer (score 0):

This will be the most similar to my current solving problem and what I would like to get. 
My goal is actually to find a way to pass this stored value which was called in class b(from my example) and passed as instance of class a and then inherit it to class c
Code:

```
class a(object):
    def __init__(self, king):
        self.yes = king 

    def passing(self):
        return self.yes

class c(object):
    def __init__(self, king):
        self.yes = king

    def ps(self):
        print(self.yes)

class b(a,c):
    def __init__(self, king):
        super().__init__(king = king)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bb = b(king="aaa")
    bb.ps()
```

Comment: This won't work. With respect, study more about Python classes, constructors, instances and inheritance. Think of class inheritance more like encapsulation than calls. The constructor is a special case. Maybe this will help: https://www.python-course.eu/python3_inheritance.php

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions and I wil refer to it and learn more from it. But may I ask why is it not working? Somehow, it produces the results I wanted it to have. 1) I wanted to create 3 different classes and with two classes hold the same instances which has been inserted by one class. Example, class a and class c should take the instance value inserted by class b. With this, I can then have different states for each class.

Comment: The constructor for class C is not invoked. king is stored only in the instance of class a. You can comment out the constructor in class c and you get the same result. Why not just use instances of the same class?  i.e create a class called king. Make the constructor save properties of king e.g. name, define the functions you want on king (like ps in your example), then just create two instances of king, i.e. king1 = king("Arthur"), king2 = king("William"). Then king1.ps() will give "Arthur" and king2.ps() "William". One class, two instances of the same class = storing two different values.

Comment: I understand what you meant, but what I wanted to try out like I specified early in my post is to try out the super() in a different way and to see whether is there a possibility to use super() to inherit the constructor values from another class which has been updated by other class.

Comment: My goal is to pass around the values to other classes and not just 1 class but multiple classes

Comment: You can. If you mean via the constructor, change call each Parent constructor instead of super().__init__(king = king), do a.__init__(self,king = king) and c.__init__(self,king = king) BUT if you call things by the same names you will not be able to access the inherited instances asyou may expect due to the names clash. Read about how python searches for attributes inherited from a parent classes section 9.5.1 here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html and https://data-flair.training/blogs/python-multiple-inheritance/